# I have a dll, Prorfl.dll from HotelLock. I am integrating it into my Access VBA, but it is giving error nor result

Tags: ms-access, dll, dllimport, vba7

The `Prorfl.dll` has been referenced as follows

```
Declare Function initializeUSB Lib "C:\Klax\WKNL\proRFL.dll" (ByVal fUSB As Byte) As Boolean
```

I get an error calling the function `InitializedUSB(1)`:

> file 'C:\Klax\WKNL\proRFL.dll' not found

I have tried to be sure of the path and confirmed severally. My ultimate aim is to be able to integrate this Dll into my Access software Via VBA

Comment: Windows will produce that error if the file *or any other libraries that it references* cannot be found.  The easiest way to check is probably to try loading the library in Dependency Walker (depends.exe) and look for anything it flags as missing.  Another alternative for debugging it is "loader snaps" which can be enabled from gflags, but I'm not sure if there's a good way to see the trace info from the loader snaps tool in Access (my experience was native debugging from Visual Studio).

Comment: What kind of .dll? Is that a standard windows x32 (or x64) bit .dll, or is that a COM object dll that requires a instance of the object to be created in VBA with create object? Regardless of above, do keep in mind with what  you shared so far, ,that suggests un-managed code, and that means the bit size of the .dll must match the bit size of Access. So, if  your running access x32 bits, then the .dll must be x32 bits. If you running Access x64 bits, then the .dll in question has to be x64 bits.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I *think* it would be a different error if the problem was a bitness mismatch.  I think it's more likely that the problem is a missing dependency.

Comment: @Graig, Let me try and look for a way to test with your suggestions..

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal They are both 32 bits.

Comment: @Craig, I can confirm that the error message is file not found when in fact the file exists and you have a bit size miss-match.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal The DLL file is 32 Bit, so is Access. Windows is 64but but I don't think windows bit could affect it. However, can I zip and upload the files?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal OK, thanks for the correction.  I already knew the error reporting for these failures was a disaster, it's even worse than I thought.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal what do you suggest way forward, The DLL is not available in 64bit , after searching the internet.  The Prorfl.dll is only available in 32bit.

Comment: the OS bit size never mattered. After all for the last 10+ years, office/Access by default been x32 bits. However, in the last 2 years, the default bit size install of office is now .x64 bits. So that's a recent change. I would double check that you ARE running office/access x32 bits. The other issue, remember for any zip file after downloading, you have to unblock the zip file BEFORE you un-zip, else all the .dll's inside will also be blocked. So, you WILL have to run/install office x32, and that's still a common install + setup on even windows OS of x64 bits (OS = x64 bits for 10_ years now)

Comment: The way forward? You have to install Office/Access x32 bits to use + consume x32 bit software - you don't really have any choice here. Bit size of code having to match is a requirement for all software and you can't mix and match software as a different bit size. So, solution is to install + use Access x32 bits. See post below on how to check the current bit size of Office/Access you are running.

Comment: So the OS of x64 bits does not really matter, and you are free to use + install x32 bit software. In fact QuickBooks, or even Sage are still x32 bits accounting packages, and they don't even have/offer x64 bit versions of those accounting packages. So, running office/Access x32 not a problem, only that you have to check/ensure/test/be sure that you installed office x32, since as noted in about the last 2 years, office/Access now by default is x64 bits. So, check the bit size of Access.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I have unblocked Zip file, The Access is 32bits and the Dll file is also 32bits. I am still getting the error message File Not Found. I wish to share the file with you.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Using dependency Walker, Just found out that the Prorfl.dll depends on two other DLLs, D12c.dll and D12.dll. there's also Prorfl.lib in the file I just got. How do I get all these into my VBA code so that the Prorfl.dll can run. Thank you

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal This same code, tested in VB6 is working .  All Dll in the same project folder. What could be the issue with VBA?

Comment: Does the VBA compile correctly? (don't run the code but compile by using debug-> compile option from vba menu

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal It compiles without error in VBA.

Comment: Well, if it works in VB6, then it should work in VBA. They both follow the same syntax. As noted, with any recent versions of VBA, then SafePtr should be required, and the compiler should warn and suggest as such. The link you provided (for test download) does not work, and google reports the link as invalid.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Let me package the files again and share . is it possible to attach it here? It's been a nightmare. Hopefully you will be able to troubleshoot it.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal [Link] <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6c2IHGgtuQPbUlybk2I-ItU7gEFKBma/view?usp=sharing> Check it out, The VB6 sample also there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, and suggested in the comments and discussion here, the only requirement to use x32 bit. dll’s is to ensure that you are running office/Access x32 bits.

From Access, (2010-2013), then go

File-Help, and you see this:

[image]

Note above - how we see x32 bits.

For 2016 (and later), then

File->Account

You see this:

[image]

You thus/then have to click on About Access, and you see this:

[image]

So, once again, I'm running x32 bit Access/office in above, and this is despite the windows OS being x64 bits. As noted, the windows OS for at least 10+ years has been defaulted to x64 bits, and your OS version will in near all cases these days be x64 bits, and that does not matter, nor effect the ability to install Access/Office x32 bits.

As I stated, this was a common setup, and still is. However, now by default, most installs of office are now defaulting x64 bits.

So, you can't mix and match x32 bit software with x64 bit software (and the reverse is also true).

Hence, your office/Access install has to match the bit size of that supplied .dll.

## Edit: Follow up and solution

Ok, so the .dll code should work. The issue is that the current default path (folder) name needs to be set. In most cases, this is not required, but since additional .dlls depend on the referenced .dll, then you HAVE to change the current directory to the current folder where the addtional .dll's exist.

Interesting, but in Access 2016/2019, the posted code just works.

But, in Access 2010, the posted code DOES NOT work.

So, this issue has to do with having set the "default" folder for Access to use on startup.

Hence, before using any of the "declared" functions, simply execute a change folder in VBA.

Hence this code works:

```
Sub Test2()


   ChDir CurrentProject.Path
   
   Debug.Print initializeUSB(mP)
   
   
End Sub
```

So, Access does not seem able to pick up the .dll's unless you first execute a folder change, so Access can see/use/find the additional .dlls referenced.

You can also create a shortcut to the accdb, but to avoid this issue, simply execute a change folder to the current folder.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I've. Checked and I can infer that the Prorfl.dll calls other DLL files. How do I link them in VBA?

Comment: As a general rule placing the other required  dlls in the same location as the referenced dll should work.  I assume you do a debug compile while in the vba code editor to ensure no syntax errors.  You should require use of SafePtr in your code

Comment: I have placed all the .dll and .lib in the dame folder.  **I'm Still getting the same Error.**

Comment: You have to provide more information here and some sample code. We are not at your computer, and thus are quite much in the dark here. We don't know the API and entry points for that sample code, and we are MORE in the dark here then you are.  We not even sure if that .dll is a COM object, or a standard .dll with standard windows entry points.

Comment: I do not have more information on the DLL. It is as provided by the Vendor. I wish i know how to upload it here so that you can test also. My own code is 'Option Compare Database

Declare Function GetDLLVersion Lib "C:\proRFL.dll" (ByVal sDllVer As String) As Integer
Declare Function initializeUSB Lib "C:\proRFL.dll" (ByVal fUSB As Byte) As Integer


Function Test()
MsgBox initializeUSB(1)

End Function'

Comment: See my edit, and posted solution.